# Create custom type that will seem like the another when checking types Golang

Tags: go, types

I am a experienced python programmer but I am still new to Golang so my apologies if this is an obvious or silly question. But I am trying to create my own type that I want to act exactly like the base type with the exception of several methods being overridden. The reason for this is because several libraries I am using are checking the type against `time.Time` and I want it to match.

```
type PythonTime struct {
    time.Time
}

var pythonTimeFormatStr = "2006-01-02 15:04:05-0700"

func (self *PythonTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    // removes prepending/trailing " in the string
    if b[0] == '"' && b[len(b)-1] == '"' {
        b = b[1 : len(b)-1]
    }
    self.Time, err = time.Parse(pythonTimeFormatStr, string(b))
    return
}

func (self *PythonTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(self.Time.Format(pythonTimeFormatStr)), nil
}

type OtherType struct {
    Uuid     string     `json:"uuid`
    Second   PythonTime `json:"second"`
    Location string     `json:"location"`
    Action   string     `json:"action"`
    Duration int        `json:"duration"`
    Value    string     `json:"value"`
}
```

So the the above works fine for marshalling and unmarshalling JSON. However, for my library that I am using (gocql and cqlr) they are checking if the type is a `time.Time` type so they can make some other modifications before putting it in C*. How do  I get my `PythonTime` type to equate to either show as `time.Time`  or override the default marshalling/unmarshalling for a `time.Time` object just for the use of my `OtherType` objects?

My temporary solution has been to modify their code and add a special case for the `PythonTime` type that does the same thing as the `time.Time` type. However, this is causing me circular imports and is not the best solution. Here is their code with my modifications.

```
func marshalTimestamp(info TypeInfo, value interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case Marshaler:
        return v.MarshalCQL(info)
    case int64:
        return encBigInt(v), nil
    case time.Time:
        if v.IsZero() {
            return []byte{}, nil
        }
        x := int64(v.UTC().Unix()*1e3) + int64(v.UTC().Nanosecond()/1e6)
        return encBigInt(x), nil
    case models.PythonTime:
        x := int64(v.UTC().Unix()*1e3) + int64(v.UTC().Nanosecond()/1e6)
        return encBigInt(x), nil
    }

    if value == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }

    rv := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    switch rv.Type().Kind() {
    case reflect.Int64:
        return encBigInt(rv.Int()), nil
    }
    return nil, marshalErrorf("can not marshal %T into %s", value, info)
}
```

Comment: You can't make a type that is the same as another. Each `type` declaration is an entirely new type.

Comment: That type switch is first checking for a `MarshalCQL` interface. Have you tried implementing that?

Comment: No, I haven't. I dont know how to make mine show as type Marshaller

Comment: You implement the methods. Interfaces are very much a core concept in Go. Some documentation from [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types), and in the [Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/methods/9)

Comment: I see now, that makes a lot more sense. I will implement a `MarshalCQL` method.

Comment: @JimB post as answer so I can select it.

Comment: I made an example based on the gocql docs. I haven't run it against cassandra, but it does correctly marshal and unmarshal back to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you have done with the [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [`json.Unamrshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler), you can also implement the [`gocql.Marshaler`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gocql/gocql#Marshaler) [`gocql.Unamrshaler`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gocql/gocql#Unmarshaler) interfaces.

```
func (t *PythonTime) MarshalCQL(info gocql.TypeInfo) ([]byte, error) {
    b := make([]byte, 8)
    x := t.UnixNano() / int64(time.Millisecond)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(b, uint64(x))
    return b, nil
}

func (t *PythonTime) UnmarshalCQL(info gocql.TypeInfo, data []byte) error {
    x := int64(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(data)) * int64(time.Millisecond)
    t.Time = time.Unix(0, x)
    return nil
}
```

(note, untested in the context of CQL, but this does round-trip with itself)

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. You're checking for a `time.Time` object when you should be checking that it satisfies an interface.

```
type TimeLike interface {
    Day() int
    Format(string) string
    ...  // whatever makes a "time" object to your code!
    // looks like in this case it's
    UTC() time.Time
    IsZero() bool
}
```

then any code that expects a `time.Time` that can be substituted with a `PythonTime`, expect a `TimeLike` instead.

```
function Foo(value interface{}) int {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case TimeLike:
        return v.Day()  // works for either time.Time or models.PythonTime
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: I didn't write the switch case in the second piece of code. It is in a library I am using. All I did was add mine into it after the `time.Time`

Comment: @electrometro right, so instead of special casing `time.Time` and `models.PythonTime`, you'll special case `TimeLike`

Comment: I wanted to avoid modifying their library at all. I ended up implementing MarshalCQL on the PythonTime struct

Comment: @electrometro that's even better -- I didn't realize `Marshaler` was an interface already.

Comment: @electrometro I'm also primarily writing Python. The way it made sense to me is that Go structs are essentially Python classes, and Go interfaces describe the things those classes can do. It's duck typing!

Comment: Yeah, I have been thinking of them as classes as well. I didn't know what the interfaces were though. So that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that will not work in Go.  Your best option would be to create some import and export methods, so that you can cast your PythonTime to a time.Time and vice versa.  That will give you flexibility you desire along with compatibility with other libraries.

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"

)

func main() {

    p, e := NewFromTime(time.Now())
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    v, e := p.MarshalJSON()
    if e != nil {
         panic(e)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(v), reflect.TypeOf(p))

    t, e := p.GetTime()
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    fmt.Println(t.String(), reflect.TypeOf(t))

}

type PythonTime struct {
    time.Time
}

var pythonTimeFormatStr = "2006-01-02 15:04:05-0700"

func NewFromTime(t time.Time) (*PythonTime, error) {

b, e := t.GobEncode()
if e != nil {
    return nil, e
}

p := new(PythonTime)
e = p.GobDecode(b)
if e != nil {
    return nil, e
}

    return p, nil
}

func (self *PythonTime) GetTime() (time.Time, error) {
    return time.Parse(pythonTimeFormatStr, self.Format(pythonTimeFormatStr))
}

func (self *PythonTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    // removes prepending/trailing " in the string
    if b[0] == '"' && b[len(b)-1] == '"' {
        b = b[1 : len(b)-1]
    }
    self.Time, err = time.Parse(pythonTimeFormatStr, string(b))
    return
}

func (self *PythonTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(self.Time.Format(pythonTimeFormatStr)), nil
}
```

That should give output like this:

`2016-02-04 14:32:17-0700 *main.PythonTime`

`2016-02-04 14:32:17 -0700 MST time.Time`

Comment: Could you give an example?